# Flex Combobox: Cancel Select

Tags: apache-flex, combobox, events

I've made an itemrenderer for the combobox control that shows a button next to the label.
If a user clicks this button, the item gets removed from the dataprovider. Works so far.
When he selects an item, the combobox closes, that's ok. But I don't want it to close when he removes an item.

So is there a way to cancel the change event?
I have tried several things, but to no avail.

I have to use the combobox for layout reasons, don't have enough space to use listboxes...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In your custom itemrenderer , on **mouse down handler** stop Immediate Propogation

event.stopImmediatePropogation();

Answer (score 0):

In your custom item renderer, try canceling the event in your button's click handler.

event.stopImmediatePropogation()

Comment: In my button's click handler I can only cancel the current MouseEvent. But this event isn't responsible for triggering the change in the combobox.